# Rotate a linked list: understanding shallow/deep copy

Tags: python, linked-list, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am looking that LeetCode problem [61. Rotate List](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-list/):

> Given the `head` of a linked list, rotate the list to the right by `k` places.
>
> ### Example 1
>
> [image]

I don't understand why we have to do `tail.next = None` at the very end. Also, we did `tail = head`, so why are we not making the last node of `head = None`?

I was trying to solve the question, but could not solve it and hence I took a reference, but I am not able to understand it either.

NB: I understand that we made a circular linked list here.

```
class Solution:
    def rotateRight(self, head: Optional[ListNode], k: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if not head:
            return head
        
        # calculate size of the list and close it in a cycle
        tail = head
        size = 1
        while tail.next:
            tail = tail.next
            size += 1
        tail.next = head
        
        # calculate required number of steps, do them and break the cycle
        for i in range(size - k % size):
            tail = head
            head = head.next
        tail.next = None
        
        return head
```

Answer (score 0):

No nodes are copied here (not shallow, not deep). Only their references are. It may help to visualise this. Let's say we have a linked list with 5 values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and we have already made it circular:

```
 head 
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

We already derived that `size` is 5. Now let's say `k` is 3. That makes the loop iterate `size - k % size` times, which is 2 times.

### Iteration #1

The first iteration makes `tail` to reference the same node as `head`:

```
 tail head 
  │    │
  ▼    ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Then `head` takes on the reference that `head.next` has:

```
 tail             head
  │                │
  ▼                ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And here we see an *invariant*: at the end of each iteration, `head` will reference the node that follows after `tail`.

### Iteration #2

This iteration also makes `tail` to reference the same node as `head`:

```
                  tail head 
                   │    │
                   ▼    ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

`head` again takes on the reference that `head.next` has:

```
                  tail             head
                   │                │
                   ▼                ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Now the list is almost ready. We just need to remove the cycle. This means we break the list between `tail` and `head`. In other words, the `next` reference of the tail node must be set to `None`. Therefore we need to execute `tail.next = None`:

```
                  tail             head
                   │                │
                   ▼                ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: None │   │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The function then returns the `head` reference and both local names `head` and `tail` are now out of scope.

```
                                   (returned)
                                    │
                                    ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: None │   │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This list is just a different visual representation of this one:

```
 (returned)
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 3     │   │ val: 4     │   │ val: 5     │   │ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ───────► │ next: ──┐  │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └─────────│──┘
      ▲                                                                       │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Hope this clarifies it.